# Trailing slash at the end of Servlet uri in Websphere Application Server 9 is throwing 404, but it's working fine in WAS 7

Tags: servlets, trailing-slash, websphere-9

In my application I have a servlet which is supposed to get executed after j_security_check in WebSphere Application Server Traditional 9.0.5.4. The Login form is as below with the j_security_check

```html
<form method="POST" action="/myapp/testserv/j_security_check">
 <table cellspacing="5" >
  <tr><td align="right">User ID:</td><td><input type="text" name="j_username" size="30" value="${username}" id="username"></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="right">Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="j_password" size="30" id="password"></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td></tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

in the Web.xml the servlet is configured as follows

```html
<servlet>
 <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
 <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.test.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/testserv</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After successful login the control is trying to hit the servet http://localhost:18380/myapp/testserv/ with the trailing "/" at then end of the URI and it's giving 404 not found Exception. I tried to add custom properties as per IBM documentation as follows , but no luck with those

**com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility = true**

**com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.redirectcontextroot = true/false** (tried with both true & false) under
Server Types -> Websphere Application Server ->  -> Web Container Settings -> Web Container -> Custom properties

Interestingly the same code base is working as expected with trailing "/" in Websphere 7. Can anyone help me out with this issue.

Thanks